# Calling PHP function via AJAX setInterval function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to echo in every 5 seconds the number of users online on the platform. It's made with session. Here's the PHP function and it's working when I refresh the page. I would like to call this function via AJAX to display the data without refreshing the page. This function is in the `index.php` file:

```
function users_online() {

    global $con;

    $session = session_id();
    $time = time();
    $time_out_in_seconds = 30;
    $time_out = $time - $time_out_in_seconds;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE session = '$session'";
    $send_query = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($send_query);

    if($count == NULL) {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users_online(session, time) VALUES('$session','$time')");
    } else {
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users_online SET time = '$time' WHERE session = '$session'");
    }

    $users_online_query =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE time > '$time_out'");
    echo $count_user = mysqli_num_rows($users_online_query);
}
```

the whole index.php:

```
<?php 
include("includes/header.php");
//include("functions.php");

function users_online() {

    global $con;

        $session = session_id();
        $time = time();
        $time_out_in_seconds = 30;
        $time_out = $time - $time_out_in_seconds;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE session = '$session'";
        $send_query = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($send_query);

            if($count == NULL) {

            mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users_online(session, time) VALUES('$session','$time')");


            } else {

            mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users_online SET time = '$time' WHERE session = '$session'");


            }

        $users_online_query =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE time > '$time_out'");
        echo $count_user = mysqli_num_rows($users_online_query);
}
$message_obj = new Message($con, $userLoggedIn);

if(isset($_GET['u']))
    $user_to = $_GET['u'];
else {
    $user_to = $message_obj->getMostRecentUser();
    if($user_to == false)
        $user_to = 'new';
}

if($user_to != "new")
    $user_to_obj = new User($con, $user_to);

if(isset($_POST['post_message'])) {

    if(isset($_POST['message_body'])) {
        $body = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message_body']);
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $message_obj->sendMessage($user_to, $body, $date);
    }

}

if(isset($_POST['post'])){

    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $errorMessage = "";

    if($imageName != "") {
        $targetDir = "assets/images/posts/";
        $imageName = $targetDir . uniqid() . basename($imageName);
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($imageName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] > 10000000) {
            $errorMessage = "Sorry your file is too large";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if(strtolower($imageFileType) != "jpeg" && strtolower($imageFileType) != "png" && strtolower($imageFileType) != "jpg") {
            $errorMessage = "Sorry, only jpeg, jpg and png files are allowed";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($uploadOk) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $imageName)) {
                //image uploaded okay
            }
            else {
                //image did not upload
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    if($uploadOk) {
        $post = new Post($con, $userLoggedIn);
        $post->submitPost($_POST['post_text'], 'none', $imageName);
    }
    else {
        echo "<div style='text-align:center;' class='alert alert-danger'>
                $errorMessage
            </div>";
    }

}


 ?>
<script>
function loadUsersOnline() {
    $.get("index.php?onlineusers=result", function(data){
        $(".usersonline").text(data);
    });
}
setInterval(function(){
    loadUsersOnline();
},5000);
</script>
    <div class="user_details column">
        <a href="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>">  <img src="<?php echo $user['profile_pic']; ?>"> </a>

        <div class="user_details_left_right">
            <a href="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>">
            <?php 
            echo $user['first_name'] . " " . $user['last_name'];

             ?>
            </a>
            <br>
            <?php echo "Posts: " . $user['num_posts']. "<br>"; 
            echo "Likes: " . $user['num_likes']. "<br>";

            ?>
            <p>Users Online: <span class='usersonline'></span><?php users_online(); ?></p>
        </div>

    </div>
<!-- I called the function above and that'the way it works by refreshing the page but the ajax script should work between spans -->
    <div class="main_column column">
        <form class="post_form" action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <textarea name="post_text" id="post_text" placeholder="Got something to say?"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="post" id="post_button" value="Post">
            <div class="file-drop-area">
                <span class="fake-btn">Choose files</span>
                <span class="file-msg js-set-number">or drag and drop files here</span>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="file-input">
            </div>
            <script  src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
        </form>

        <div class="posts_area"></div>

        <!-- <button id="load_more">Load More Posts</button> -->
        <img id="loading" src="assets/images/icons/loading.gif">


    </div>

    <div class="user_details column">

        <h4>Popular</h4>

        <div class="trends">
            <?php 
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM trends ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 9");

            foreach($query as $row) {

                $word = $row['title'];
                $word_dot = strlen($word) >= 14 ? "..." : "";

                $trimmed_word = str_split($word, 14);
                $trimmed_word = $trimmed_word[0];

                echo "<div style'padding: 1px'>";
                echo $trimmed_word . $word_dot;
                echo "<br></div><br>";


            }

            ?>
        </div>


    </div>


    <div class="user_details column" id="conversations">
            <h4>Conversations</h4>

            <div class="loaded_conversations">
                <?php echo $message_obj->getConvos(); ?>
            </div>
            <br>
            <a href="messages.php?u=new">New Message</a>

        </div>




    <script>
    var userLoggedIn = '<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>';

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#loading').show();

        //Original ajax request for loading first posts 
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
            cache:false,

            success: function(data) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('.posts_area').html(data);
            }
        });

        $(window).scroll(function() {
        //$('#load_more').on("click", function() {

            var height = $('.posts_area').height(); //Div containing posts
            var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
            var page = $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').val();
            var noMorePosts = $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').val();

            if ((document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) && noMorePosts == 'false') {
            //if (noMorePosts == 'false') {
                $('#loading').show();

                var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
                    url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "page=" + page + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
                    cache:false,

                    success: function(response) {
                        $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage 
                        $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage 
                        $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePostsText').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage 

                        $('#loading').hide();
                        $('.posts_area').append(response);
                    }
                });

            } //End if 

            return false;

        }); //End (window).scroll(function())


    });

    </script>




    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't. If it takes the client longer than 500ms to receive the data (and it will) this will eventually crash the client.

Comment: what to do then?

Comment: setTimeout, at the least, but i'd also suggest increasing the time to at least 5 seconds. If you want to go any faster than that, don't use ajax.

Comment: The number of users online isn't critical information, hammering your server to retrieve it is a terrible idea.

Comment: 5 seconds would be ok. Can you help out with the  ajax code?

Comment: I'd like to make a social network and it would be a really usefull feature

Comment: I'm not saying don't display it, i'm saying maybe it'd be better to just pass it along with other requests instead of sending a request just for this info. Surely there's other requests occurring as the user interacts with the page.

Comment: No, there isn't any ajax or javascript requests yet. Everything is written in objected oriented php.

Comment: I've added a pic too, so it should be clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pull the data with AJAX, you seem to get back the contents of your `index.php` and then you copy that into the span. Your `index.php` does not include a check for the get variables and the function never gets called. Therefore add a line like this at the top of your `index.php`, right the next line after `<?php`, *before* `include("includes/header.php");`:

```
if ( array_key_exists( "onlineusers", $_GET ) &&
     "result" == $_GET[ "onlineusers" ] ) {
    echo users_online();
    exit();
}
```

Also, a side note, I'd suggest you review the [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) MySQL function to simplify your query into something like this, your MySQL server will thank you for not requesting the full table unnecessarily for each query:

```
$users_online_query =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM users_online WHERE time > '$time_out'");
```

Adding to all the other commenters so far, I'd advise to give performance issues a serious consideration with this application. Depending on how many users you're expecting to have, the burden on the server can significant. On the other hand, some carefully tuned cache settings can work wonders. For example setting the expiration on the AJAX URL to 5 seconds allows all repeater stations to cache the number for 5 seconds so even if you have 10k users requesting the same thing at the same time, most of them will be served by caches somewhere.

Comment: Thank you that you've tried to help me out with an exact answer but it doesn't work yet. I don't have that much experience in programming yet but I really want to progress and solve this problem. Can I send you my whole index.php somewhere so you can have a clearer overview of the code I've written? Lots of thanks!

Comment: Yes sure, make a copy named `index_copy.txt` or similar, post the URL and I'll download.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I couldn't add any link to the OP but I edited it and posted the whole code! Thank you in advance! Köszönöm!!! :)

Comment: Posting the code here is actually the better way because the question will make sense to new visitors as well. :) Updated my answer, you need to put those five lines right at the top. Let me know what happens. Didn't know you spoke Hungarian but: szívesen! :)

Comment: Now I'm getting back less content from my index.php file but it still doesn't work. I'm not really sure that the function gets called to be honest. I think that my problem might be here. Or the 'result' is not what I expect to be: 
 $.get("index.php?onlineusers=result", function(data){
        $(".usersonline").text(data);
    });

Comment: I put that if you wrote me right after the php tag but it doesn't echo anything

Comment: What do you get back when you call `localhost/index.php?onlineusers=result` manually from the browser? (If I remember the URL correcly from the screenshot.)

Comment: Ah our comments just crossed. So separate the two lines at the end of the `users_online()` function, first assign `$count_users` then echo it. Also, add something to the echo, like `echo "foobar" . $count_user to be sure the echo runs at all. (By the way, the extra echo is unnecessary in my code, just realized.)

Comment: if I enter localhost/index.php?onlineusers=result manually i get errors like this: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Demo/index.php on line 20. If I echo a string just like you said, I get that contant back too but after that the string appears too. So it seems that my queries don't work

Comment: This means the variable in that line, `$con`, which you declare as global at the top of the function, does not contain a valid mysqli connection handle. I suspect your `header.php` contains the `$con = mysqli_connect( ... )` command, which we don't invoke in this case. I suggest you copy that line out from `header.php` and insert it in the `user_online()` function, right after `global $con;` with an if, like `if ( null == $con ) { $con = mysqli_connect( ... ); } so that if we're not connected to MySQL yet when the function runs, we make sure to connect.

Comment: Sure :) Nagyon szívesen, Ottó! :)